# How to swap Primary Monitor with a keybind?

Tags: display

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME, and would like to be able to change which of my 2 monitors is currently the Primary Display, using a keybind. I can't seem to figure out how to do it, and the information i am able to find are all from older versions of Ubuntu.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not have dual monitors myself, but perhaps check the Super+P default shortcut key. This will display a dialog. I expect, however, that that may not allow to change the primary monitor, only whether to join or mirror displays, or turn one or another off.